# Problems recording information in the msdb..suspect_pages table were encountered (Error code 3624)

Tags: sql-server

Trying to restore a full database backup plus the latest differential from a production database to a different database (staging) I started to randomly get the following error:

> Msg 3624, Level 20, State 1, Server xxxxxx, Line 2 A system
>   assertion check has failed. Check the SQL Server error log for
>   details.
>
> Typically, an assertion failure is caused by a software bug
>   or data corruption. To check for database corruption, consider running
>   DBCC CHECKDB. If you agreed to send dumps to Microsoft during setup, a
>   mini dump will be sent to Microsoft. An update might be available from
>   Microsoft in the latest Service Pack or in a Hotfix from Technical
>   Support.
>
> Problems recording information in the `msdb..suspect_pages`
>   table were encountered. This error does not interfere with any
>   activity except maintenance of the suspect_pages table. Check the
>   error log for more information.

After that I can read from the logs

> RESTORE DATABASE successfully processed 17725 pages in 1.754 seconds (78.947 MB/sec).

And I can also confirm that the database is working properly.

This is happening on a Microsoft SQL Server 2014 (SP1-GDR) (KB3194720) - 12.0.4232.0 (X64)

So my question is. Where can I find information about error 3624?

Seems to be related with the table `msdb..suspect_pages` not being accessible at the moment of the restore.

Comment: Did you actually follow the advice and issue `DBCC CHECKDB` on both `msdb` and the database you restored? If not, you should.

Comment: Yes I did and the error is coming back every now and then.

Comment: Does `msdb.dbo.suspect_pages` actually contain any rows?

Comment: Not for the database I am restoring

Comment: If it contains *any* rows, regardless of database, it means the server has had to repair problems with data pages. That's not an indication of a healthy server.

Comment: Well the record has the event_type of 4 which means that Restored (The page was restored after it was marked bad) and it is from the last year (2016-08-01 18:21:03.873)